# ASP Authetification Authorize adding

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to add authorize to my project knowing that the authentification work well

This is my Login method :

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User u)
    {
            var v = db.users.Where(a => a.Email.Equals(u.Email) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password) ).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v !=null)
            {
               int priv=v.PrivilegeID;
                Session["LoginuseID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                Session["Loginusename"] = v.Nom.ToString();
                if ( priv == 1)
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("indexuser", "Home");

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(u);
            }

        //return View();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you wanna use Identity for auth?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseController which derives from the Controller class, Annotate it with the Authorize Attribute and then extend the AppController in Other Controllers in your application, for the methods where you don't require Authorization or Authentication use the [AllowAnonymous] Attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class AppController : Controller
{

}


public class HomeController : AppController 
{
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Login { return View();}
}
```

Comment: Hello Can I add authorize in home controler directly or what should I write in AppControler

Comment: Yes you can add it in the Home controller directly.. but you would have to do the same for all your controllers, and add the allow anonymous attribute where you dont need it like your login method